# ImportError: cannot import name 'NeuroPy'

Tags: python, numpy, python-requests, python-3.9, pybrain

```
from NeuroPy import NeuroPy

object1=NeuroPy("COM6") 

def attention_callback(attention_value):
    print ("Value of attention is",attention_value)
    return None

object1.setCallBack("attention",attention_callback)

object1.start()

while True:
    if(object1.meditation>70):
        object1.stop()
```

I run this code and get this error:

```
$ python thread.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "thread.py", line 1, in <module>
    from NeuroPy import NeuroPy
  File "D:\pu\fyp\neuro\NeuroPy.py", line 1, in <module>
    from NeuroPy import NeuroPy
ImportError: cannot import name 'NeuroPy'
```

I changed my file name to NeuroPy.py but it makes no difference. I also changed

```
from NeuroPy import NeuroPy
```

to

```
from NeuroPy.NeuroPy import NeuroPy
```

and

```
object1=NeuroPy("COM6")
```

to

```
object1=NeuroPy.NeuroPy("COM6")
```

but I still face some errors

```
from NeuroPy.NeuroPy import NeuroPy

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'NeuroPy.NeuroPy'; 'NeuroPy' is not a package
```

Answer (score 1):

NeuroPy is not part of the Python standard library so you have to install it before you can import it.

The command for this is

```
pip install NeuroPy
```

And you should absolutely *not* name your program `NeuroPy.py` even after you have installed the module, and if you have a program of that name, delete or rename it. Otherwise, your program will shadow the module you are trying to import.